# install other packages when creating new package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I created a R package called `myPackage`. In that package I've used other packages, such as, `RJSONIO`, `stringr`, `RSQLite` and `Rcpp`. I want to install all of those packages when I am installing `myPackage`, if it is not installed before.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a list of packages in the `DEPENDS` section of your [DESCRIPTION](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) file. From the linked documentation file

> The ‘Depends’ field gives a comma-separated list of package names
>   which this package depends on. The package name may be optionally
>   followed by a comment in parentheses. The comment should contain a
>   comparison operator, whitespace and a valid version number. You can
>   also use the special package name ‘R’ if your package depends on a
>   certain version of R — e.g., if the package works only with R version
>   2.11.0 or later, include ‘R (>= 2.11.0)’ in the ‘Depends’ field. You can also require a certain SVN revision for R-devel or R-patched, e.g.
>   ‘R (>= 2.14.0), R (>= r56550)’ requires a version later than R-devel
>   of late July 2011 (including released versions of 2.14.0). Both
>   library and the R package checking facilities use this field: hence it
>   is an error to use improper syntax or misuse the ‘Depends’ field for
>   comments on other software that might be needed. Other dependencies
>   (external to the R system) should be listed in the
>   ‘SystemRequirements’ field, possibly amplified in a separate README
>   file. The R INSTALL facilities check if the version of R used is
>   recent enough for the package being installed, and the list of
>   packages which is specified will be attached (after checking version
>   requirements) before the current package, both when library is called
>   and when preparing for lazy-loading during installation.

There are other related sections, such as `IMPORTS` and `SUGGESTS` - see the docs for details.

Have a look at some of the R-packages on r-forge to get an idea.

Comment: in desription file i put the depends field like this.
Depends: Rcpp (>= 0.09.10),RJSONIO,stringr,RSQLite
But an error occured during R CMD INSTALL.
The error is as follows:
ERROR: dependency ‘RJSONIO’ is not available for package ‘Mypackage’

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to install the package from your file system, i.e. `install.package("pg.0.1.1.tar.gz")` This sets your repository to the local file system, so it won't download RJSONIO automatically - see `?install.package`

Comment: so is this possible only if install directly from CRAN ?

Comment: To answer your **exact** question - no. But, it has to do with local package installation and `getOptions("repo")`. I would suggest asking another question regarding this specific matter.