# Ensuring another package exists in my new R package

Tags: r, package

I am creating a new R package (called `MyPackage`) and I'd like it to include `ggplot2` within it. That is, when the user runs the command `install.packages("MyPackage", repos="repo goes here")`, it will check for `ggplot2` and install `ggplot2` if it is not already installed. Additionally, when a user runs the command `library(MyPackage)`, somehow the command `library(ggplot2)` will also be called.

How can I do this?

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761004/install-other-packages-when-creating-new-package-in-r?rq=1

Comment: Have you read the [Writing R Extensions Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies)??

Comment: This is discussed in great detail in [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't see this pdf yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `Depends: ggplot2` -- see the Writing R Extensions manual.  This will load and attach the package to the user's search path and is equivalent to him/her doing `library(ggplot2)`.

You could also use `Imports:` in case you wanted narrower, more specific behavior where your package uses one or more functions from the ggplot2 package, but you did not want to load it to the user's search path.  This is now the preferred programming method as it is somewhat undesirable to inflate the search path.